# How to Select Input Fields that are Dynamically added to DOM via Ajax

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple browser extension that run a small piece of code to force the browser to remember passwords.

```
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="password"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].autocomplete="on";   
  }
```

But with the above code, it's not working on web pages where the input fields are dynamically added to the DOM via Ajax.

Is there any way to keep a listener and then set `autocomplete="on"` for dynamically added `off` fields  in the DOM after the Ajax call.

Comment: What do you mean? `querySelectorAll` happily finds dynamically added elements.

Comment: Perhaps, you're checking _before_ they're added. In this case, check a bit later.

Comment: Sorry I meant for input fields that are dynamically added to the DOM via Ajax. Any way to listen and add the autocomplete attribute? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: You don't "add anything via AJAX" - it is a communication paradigm. You add via `innerHTML`, `appendChild`, or some library wrapper over those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. **BUT**

You should go to the code that adds the fields with the AJAX and have it add the input nodes with the `autocomplete` property set to `true`.

If you don't want to do that (please do that), you can use a **[MutationObserver](https://devdocs.io/dom/mutationobserver)** to know when new nodes are added to the DOM.